# Create test hierarchy with @TestFactory

Tags: testing, junit, junit5

I'm using the Junit 5 annotation `@TestFactory` to generate several tests like this :

```
@TestFactory
public Collection<DynamicTest> myTest() throws IOException {
    return fetchSomeTests().stream()
            .map(test -> {
                return dynamicTest(test.get("testDescription"), () -> doMyTest(test));
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is it possible to organize generated tests in groups, just like when you use different classes of `@Test` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Use `Collection<DynamicNode>` as the return type and create as many groups as you want.

Copied from: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests

*`DynamicContainer` instances are composed of a display name and a list of dynamic child nodes, enabling the creation of arbitrarily nested hierarchies of dynamic nodes.*

Here is a sample generating nested dynamic containers and tests:

```
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicNode> dynamicTestsWithContainers() {
    return Stream.of("A", "B", "C")
        .map(input -> dynamicContainer("Container " + input, Stream.of(
            dynamicTest("not null", () -> assertNotNull(input)),
            dynamicContainer("properties", Stream.of(
                dynamicTest("length > 0", () -> assertTrue(input.length() > 0)),
                dynamicTest("not empty", () -> assertFalse(input.isEmpty()))
            ))
        )));
}
```

It results in a tree like:

```
│  ├─ DynamicTestsDemo ✔
│  │  ├─ dynamicTestsWithContainers() ✔
│  │  │  ├─ Container A ✔
│  │  │  │  ├─ not null ✔
│  │  │  │  └─ properties ✔
│  │  │  │     ├─ length > 0 ✔
│  │  │  │     └─ not empty ✔
│  │  │  ├─ Container B ✔
│  │  │  │  ├─ not null ✔
│  │  │  │  └─ properties ✔
│  │  │  │     ├─ length > 0 ✔
│  │  │  │     └─ not empty ✔
│  │  │  └─ Container C ✔
│  │  │     ├─ not null ✔
│  │  │     └─ properties ✔
│  │  │        ├─ length > 0 ✔
│  │  │        └─ not empty ✔
```

Comment: This is perfect :)